# Elegant way evaluating determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$\left| A \right| = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   a & 1 & {1 - a} & 0  \\
   0 & a & 1 & {1 - a}  \\
   {1 - b} & 1 & b & 0  \\
   0 & {1 - b} & 1 & b  \\
\end{array}} \right|$$

For the matter of fact, $\left| A \right| = 0$.
How can I show it without calculating it step-by-step which is relatively exhausting.

I was able to observe that the sum of each row is $2$.

Comment: Just because the sum of each row is the same doesn't mean that the determinant is zero (or help you for that in any way), since you can just normalize the rows and pull out factors for each row to have the same row sum. In fact, if you had a $n \times n$ matrix where each row was drawn from the Euclidean unit sphere uniformly (or indeed, many continuous distributions), it would almost surely have nonzero determinant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one column (row) of a matrix can be written as a linear combination of the others then the matrix has a zero determinant. Here, column 1 = column 2 $-$ column 3 $+$ column 4.

$$\begin{align}
a &= 1 - (1-a) + 0\\
0 &= a - 1 + (1-a)\\
1-b &= 1 - b + 0\\
0 &= (1-b) -1 +b
\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh right. Thanks! :)

Comment: +1, but i thought $c_1 + c_3 = c_2 + c_4$ is easier to see...

Comment: @gt6989b thankyou, you're right it is!